# What child seats have a quick-release mechanism?

Tags: child-seat

I'm looking to purchase a rear child seat for my almost-two-year-old.

The main feature I'm interested in is being able to very quickly and easily take it on and off.

This Yepp Maxi I saw in a store here in NYC fits the description but it is $210+ and that's more than I wanted to spend.  [REI link for Yepp Maxi](http://www.rei.com/webservices/rei/DisplayStyle/815613?source=gpla&cm_mmc=cse_froogle-_-datafeed-_-product-_-815613&mr%3atrackingCode=56024905-8C51-E011-BB8E-001B21631C34&mr%3areferralID=NA)

What others are out there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Topeak makes a lot of quick release products that integrate with their rack which has rails for all of their gear to slide into. Here is a picture of their baby seat.
[image: http://www.topeak.com/products/Child-Carrier/babyseat_wrack]

Comment: Cool, thanks! The only issue I can foresee is that it doesn't have a locking mechanism, but I don't know if people steal these things or not.

Comment: UPDATE: I purchased this from Amazon, but mistakenly didn't notice they make a BabySeat **II** version and that is what is compatible with the bag accessories and whatnot. Big mistake. Note to future buyers, make sure you get the **II** version.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a late response but others like me might still refer to this page for advice. (I know I did read up on this before we made our decision)

We have just brought a Soosi Flinger bike seat for our 14 month old, 10 kg toddler. He loves sitting in it! It must be comfortable enough as he fell asleep in it during a ride! My husband likes the seat/bracket system because it is quick to take the seat off when he rides his bike to work.

Here is a link to the manufacturer's website: http://soosi.flinger.com.tw/sw-bc07-1.html

Answer (score 0):

In my experience almost all of them have some form of quick release, but few are really lockable.

At least some of the CoPilot, Hamax, [BoBike](http://www.gazellebicycles.com.au/products/bobike-child-bike-seats/mini-front-child-seat.html), Beto and [OK Baby](http://www.okbaby.it/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=103:orion&catid=19:ciclo&Itemid=91&lang=en) seats are quick release and the OK Baby one is lockable. Most will sell you multiple mounts so you can easily use the same seat with multiple bikes. Check the desciption on the seats you're interested in, as I would not suggest buying based on quick release as a major factor.

[image: OK Baby Orion baby seat][image: OK Baby locking system]

On the other hand, most of them have a mounting system that bolts onto the bike and is tedious to remove. So someone stealing the seat would need to buy a new mount for it. They'd probably just steal the whole bike.

Answer (score 0):

I picked up a Soosi 'Flinger' (terrible name for a child seat huh?!) from my local bike shop recently for my 1.5 year old and it has been really good.

There is a bracket which stays on the bike but rest can easily be clicked in and out without too much fuss.

I was unable to find any info on the company, which is usually a bad sign, but the seat has been good so far, seems strong and my child is comfortable in it.  It's not a fancy seat by any means but does the job.
[image: Kids Bike Seat]

Answer (score 0):

We have used a [Co-Pilot bike seat](http://www.wiggle.co.uk/co-pilot/cycle/child-seats/) for some time and have found it to be excellent.

It is quick to fit and release (30 seconds maybe). It looks to be a good deal cheaper in the UK than the one you've found in NYC, not sure where your nearest stockist is, but you can pick them up on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B000G22QHW) for $99 currently.